# Create Jenkins Job remotely with REST API /jenkins/createItem

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our system will continuously create pipelines through Jenkins' createItem api, but this interface has been responding very slowly for unknown reasons recently. According to the monitoring of the Jenkins background, we can see that the doCreateItem threads are all blocked.
One of the blocked threads：

```
    Handling POST /jenkins/createItem from 10.68.7.163 : http-bio-10.68.2.193-8443-exec-19175" #446734     daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa9d0aaa800 nid=0x2a43 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fa8b6d7d000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doCreateItem(Jenkins.java:3982)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000247005508> (a hudson.model.Hudson)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1326180498.invokeVirtual_L3_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/49195642.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1839787849.invoker(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/368369288.invokeExact_MT(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
```

There is the thread dump：

```
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.current(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.NativeThreadSet.add(NativeThreadSet.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:207)

    locked <0x000000048c8f7180> (a java.lang.Object)
    at hudson.util.FileChannelWriter.write(FileChannelWriter.java:73)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.write(AtomicFileWriter.java:166)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:73)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.write(QuickWriter.java:61)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.endNode(PrettyPrintWriter.java:316)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.endNode(WriterWrapper.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.path.PathTrackingWriter.endNode(PathTrackingWriter.java:48)
    at    com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionCon    verter.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeSetConverter.marshal(TreeSetConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:264)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:251)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:223)
    at    com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1026)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1015)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:988)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:195)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.save(Descriptor.java:892)
eliminated <0x000000024042f8b8> (a org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval.configuring(ScriptApproval.java:453)
    locked <0x000000024042f8b8> (a org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition.readResolve(CpsFlowDefinition.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.callReadResolve(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshalField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:408)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:330)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:269)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1053)
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:149)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:370)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn$4.call(ItemGroupMixIn.java:279)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn$4.call(ItemGroupMixIn.java:277)
    at hudson.model.Items.whileUpdatingByXml(Items.java:136)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProjectFromXML(ItemGroupMixIn.java:277)
eliminated <0x00000002492b3808> (a jenkins.model.Jenkins$2)
    at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createTopLevelItem(ItemGroupMixIn.java:190)
    locked <0x00000002492b3808> (a jenkins.model.Jenkins$2)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doCreateItem(Jenkins.java:3982)
    locked <0x0000000247005508> (a hudson.model.Hudson)
```

The picture is the monitoring information of jenkins.
jenkins monitor

[image]

I want to know the reason for this blockage
The current version of jenkins is 2.235.5